# Error in displaying the custom Content type of each list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2013, content-type

I have created several custom lists in my project and I affected to each one **a custom content type** .

After deploying the project and exploring my SharePoint site , there is only one content type which is added to all list instances.

I'm sure that the schema.xml of each list contains its custom content type ( ID and fields ).

Am I missing something else in my Project?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is resolved when I put each List Definition in a separate feature .

At first time , I used to put all List Definitions in the same feature , then I put the ID of this feature in element.xml file of each list Instance as featureId Attribute .

Automatically , each list instance references to the first List Definition of the feature , then it displays the fields and the content type related to this list Definition .

Comment: I followed your advice as stated above and your solution worked but I also found another solution. Within the list instance Element.xml file there is a fields called TemplateType and in the lists Elements.xml there is another field named "Type". If you fill both of these fields with the same value for example TemplateType=10100 and  Type=10100 on one list and then increment the values on the next list to say 10101 you will not have an issue and be able to put all artifacts into the same feature.